# How can I prevent jquery from breaking on an overlay after a validator returns Invalid?

Tags: jquery, plone

I am using Plone 4.3 and I have a form that has a validator (z3c.form.validator.SimpleValidator) that raises Invalid when a condition for a field is not met.  However, under the circumstances that a user clicks 'Submit' with invalid data and the form is opened as an overlay, the Invalid message displays, but any changes I made using jQuery revert.

I have a function that when called replaces the minutes in the start and end field (implemented from IEventBasic behavior) with 00 and 30:

```
jquery(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        modifyTEWidgets: function(){
            $('#form-widgets-IEventBasic-start-minute').replaceWith(
                '<select class="minute datetime-widget required datetime-field" id="form-widgets-IEventBasic-start-minute" name="form.widgets.IEventBasic.start-minute">\
                     <option value="00">00</option>\
                     <option value="30">30</option>\
                </select>'
            );

            $('#form-widgets-IEventBasic-end-minute').replaceWith(
                '<select class="minute datetime-widget required datetime-field" id="form-widgets-IEventBasic-end-minute" name="form.widgets.IEventBasic.end-minute">\
                     <option value="00">00</option>\
                     <option value="30">30</option>\
                 </select>'
             );                
        },
    });


});
```

In the prep overlay's config parameter, I set the onLoad option to call modifyTEWidgets()

```
$('a#my-object-myobject, .openMyObject').prepOverlay({
        subtype: 'ajax',
        filter: '#content>*',
        formselector: '#content-core > form',
        noform: 'redirect',
        config:{
                onLoad: function(e){
                        $().modifyTEWidgets();
                },

        }
});
```

I also make the same changes when the form is not accessed as a popup:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if($('body').hasClass('portaltype-my-object-myobject') || $('body').hasClass('template-my-object-myobject')){
        $().modifyTEWidgets();
    }
    ...
});
```

The problem is that when the form is accessed as an overlay, the jQuery breaks when the user clicks the submit button with invalid dates.  The minutes revert back to 0-59 and another change for hiding time components of the start and end fields if whole day is selected stops working.
What is odd is that if the user clicks on another field after leaving an invalid date, as opposed to clicking submit, it doesn't break and the Invalid message shows up as it should.  Also, the jQuery doesn't break at all if the user is accessing the form normally.

I did try using other options in the config parameter to call the modifyTEWidgets from, but I'm not sure if that's going to help as nothing changed.  Part of the problem could be the fact the start and end fields are from IEventBasic.

Is there any way to prevent the changes made in the fields from being undone when the user clicks submit with invalid data?

UPDATE
I came up with a work around finally.

```
$('#form-buttons-save').click(function(e){

    if(typeof clicked !== 'undefined'){
        //prevent submitting again
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else{
        $('.fieldErrorBox').each(function(i,obj){
            if(obj.innerHTML.length > 0){
                //prevent submitting and break loop
                e.preventDefault();
                clicked = undefined;
                return false;
            }
            //Set clicked to true since there could be a potential submission
            clicked = true;
        });
    }
    //Upon reaching this line, the submission will occur
});
```

The other thing I needed to do was to make my own check in my validator for seeing if the end date was set before the start date.  Theirs by default took place after the submit was clicked and in my case would break the jQuery change.

Comment: Not sure about the jquery issue, but perhaps [this](https://community.plone.org/t/other-time-settings-in-plone-5-events/2629) would help you do what you want another way?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure if I can implement what you are suggesting in the post, but I'm more concerned about the jQuery.  I think my changes in onLoad are being unbinded (term?) when the submit button is clicked.

Comment: I updated my question because I found I can target the button and use preventDefault

Comment: This actually doesn't work all the time.  If you change the value, and then click on another field, and then change the value to a bad value, and hit submit, it works.  However, I've come to the conclusion that either overlays aren't friendly with invalidators or overlays are not meant to be used with content types implementing the IEventBasic behavior.  Getting rid of all my jquery, the behavior itself has its own thing where it hides the time components if you set whole day to true.  If you happen to click submit with invalid data, it will break its own code.

Comment: I believe now it has to do with the event interface.  I created a different package with a jquery script that prepoverlays the Event content type.  When I open the form for adding an event normally, Whole Days hides the time components properly, but with the prepoverlay, Whole Days doesn't work at all, which is odd.  Its not just my content type.

Comment: Based on another question I asked, I ended up making my own add form template and embedded similar code in my workaround there.  I made another browserview that when called with form data passed in (i.e. an ajax call) would return a list of errors if there were any and then based on the data, prevent default and then change the styling to meet with what validators normally do.   The ajax call's async property was set to false though.